# Split an array of strings in to chunks of a maximum size

Tags: arrays, powershell

I'm attempting to ensure an array of unknown length is split in one-or-more arrays with a maximum of 20 elements.

I've searched around and found several answers for similar questions based on arrays containing number sequences (or maybe I'm just missing something), but nothing for an array of strings.

I've come up with a solution, but it seems a little convoluted and I feel it could probably be better.

For example, take this array -

```
$metricDefinitionsHash= [ordered]@{"this one" = "111"; "that one" = "222"; "another one" = "333"}
```

And for the sake of this example, that's say I want only a maximum of two elements -

```
$metricsQueryParts = @()
$counter = 0
$metricDefinitionsHash.Keys | ForEach-Object {
    $index = [System.Math]::Floor($counter / 2)
    if ($metricsQueryParts.Length -eq $index)
    {
        $metricsQueryParts += ""
        $metricsQueryParts[$index] = @()
    }
    $metricsQueryParts[$index] += $_
    $counter++
}
```

So now I have an array of arrays -

```
@(@("this one", "that one"), @("another one"))
```

But... Can I achieve my goal in a more efficient way?

Comment: Are you trying to resolve a performance problem, or something else?

Comment: No, I'd just be very surprised if there was not a better way to do what I'm doing.

Comment: Aside from a better title `...chunks of a maximum count` it's IMO quite efficient. But off topic here - maybe better suited on [CodeReview.se].

Comment: Is += on an array the equivalent of a redim in VB.net?   If so...that's quite an expensive operation...copying the whole array and creating a new one...the answer below is quite nice

Comment: @Ctznkane525 Yes, `+=` is expensive, but should be tolerable when appending in (large-enough) chunks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `for` loop, the range operator (`..`), and the unary array construction operator (`,`):

```
[array]$keys = $metricDefinitionsHash.Keys
$size = 3
$metricsQueryParts = @()
for ($i=0; $i -lt $keys.Count; $i+=$size) {
    $metricsQueryParts += ,$keys[$i..($i+$size-1)]
}
```

`[array]$keys` casts the key/value collection `.Keys` to a generic array (so that the index operator can be used on it).

The expression `$i..($i+$size-1)` gives you the indexes from $i up to the index before `$i+$size`, i.e. the next `$size` elements from the array starting at position `$i`. If there are less than `$size` elements the expression will give just the remaining number of elements.

The unary array construction operator ensures that `$keys[...]` is appended to `$metricsQueryParts` as a nested array instead of just concatenating the two arrays.

Answer (score 1):

I really like Ansgar's solution but the keys collection isn't an array and as such you can't use the array range syntax. Keys is an OrderedDictionaryKeyValueCollection. I have used out-string -stream to force the OrderedDictionaryKeyValueCollection to an array.

```
$keys = $metricDefinitionsHash.Keys | out-string -stream
$size = 2
$metricsQueryParts = @()
for ($i=0; $i -lt $keys.Count; $i+=$size) {
    $metricsQueryParts += ,$keys[$i..($i+$size-1)]
}
```

Comment: *but the keys collection isn't an array* It can be cast to one, though.

Comment: Didn't think of that